# urxvt: Inconsistent behaviour re: unicode display

Tags: unicode, utf-8, urxvt, i3-window-manager

I am using i3 as my window manager. When I open terminal using the default 
shortcut key, the resulting urxvt cannot display unicode chars. But when I open using urxvt or urxvt -ls, it can.

I've compared the outputs of `set`, `locale` and `xrdb -q` and they are identical except for random/oldpwd/time.

What could be the reason why I cannot see unicode in a terminal that is named after it?  If it matters, my file is saved in UTF8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the locale in which your window manager is running is different, that can explain the problem.  That could happen if your *system* locale differs from the locale set in your shell initialization.

Comment: That was the problem. I logged $(locale) during the init of my i3, and its all C (some empty). So I edited /etc/default/locale to the output of locale command (which has my local changes)

Comment: this answer is also relevant for the same urxvt issue in cygwin; just define windows env variable `LANG` and `LC_ALL` and it starts to work